# MultiFile Upload taking file name as caption

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using jquery-multifile v2.2.2 to upload gallery images. I would like to take the file name, delete the " _ - / etc. " symbols and use the file name as caption of the image.

How can I edit value section to take file name and edit it like I need ?

```
<input placeholder="caption" type="text" value"???" name="caption[]" id="'+element.id+'_caption'+'"></input>
```

- I'm using this script to integrate Multifile jquery :

```html
   <script type="text/javascript">
        
        $(function(){ // wait for page to load
     
    
    
      $('#withEvents').MultiFile({
        max: 20,
        onFileRemove: function(element, value, master_element) {
          $('#F9-Log').append('<li>onFileRemove - ' + value + '</li>')
        },
        afterFileRemove: function(element, value, master_element) {
          $('#F9-Log').append('<li>afterFileRemove - ' + value + '</li>')
        },
        onFileAppend: function(element, value, master_element) {
    
          $('#F9-Log').append('<li>onFileAppend - ' + value + '</li>')
        },
        afterFileAppend: function(element, value, master_element) {
          $('#F9-Log').append('<li>afterFileAppend - ' + value + '</li>')
        },
        onFileSelect: function(element, value, master_element) {
          $('#F9-Log').append('<li>onFileSelect - ' + value + '</li>')
        },
        afterFileSelect: function(element, value, master_element) {
            console.log(element, value, master_element);
            console.log('id:'+element.id);
            
            var a = '<div class="as"><input placeholder="caption" type="text" name="caption[]" id="'+element.id+'_caption'+'"></input><input name="alttext[]" placeholder="Alt text" type="text" id="'+element.id+'_alttext'+'"></input></div>';
         
        $('.MultiFile-preview:last').after(a);   
        a='';
        }
    
      });
    
    
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you mean that you just replace element.id to element.name

```
afterFileSelect: function(element, value, master_element) {
      console.log(element, value, master_element);
      console.log('id:'+element.id);
 console.log('caption:'+element.name);


      var a = '<div class="as"><input placeholder="caption" type="text" name="caption[]" id="'+element.id+'_caption'+'"></input><input name="alttext[]" placeholder="Alt text" type="text" id="'+element.id+'_alttext'+'"></input></div>';

  $('.MultiFile-preview:last').after(a);   
  a='';
  }
```

Comment: Hello, I want to use image file name as value of image caption.

Comment: Also I tried your code to take value. And It's not giving me file name.

caption:galleryImage[]

Comment: any idea? I'really didn't find any solution @anwaralamgilani

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

```
'+file.name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")+'
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(function(){ // wait for page to load
 


  $('#withEvents').MultiFile({
    max: 20,
    onFileRemove: function(element, value, master_element, file) {
      $('#F9-Log').append('<li>onFileRemove - ' + value + '</li>')
    },
    afterFileRemove: function(element, value, master_element, file) {
      $('#F9-Log').append('<li>afterFileRemove - ' + value + '</li>')
    },
    onFileAppend: function(element, value, master_element, file) {

   
      $('#F9-Log').append('<li>onFileAppend - ' + value + '</li>')
    },
    afterFileAppend: function(element, value, master_element, file) {
      $('#F9-Log').append('<li>afterFileAppend - ' + value + '</li>')
    },
    onFileSelect: function(element, value, master_element, file) {
      $('#F9-Log').append('<li>onFileSelect - ' + value + '</li>')
    },
    afterFileSelect: function(element, value, master_element, file) {
        console.log(element, value, master_element);
        console.log('id:'+element.id);
        console.log('caption:'+file.name);
    
        var a = '<div class="as"><input placeholder="caption" type="text" value="'+file.name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")+'" name="caption[]" id="'+element.id+'_caption'+'"></input><input name="alttext1[]" placeholder="Alt text" type="text" id="'+element.id+'_alttext1'+'"></input></div>';
       
    $('.MultiFile-preview:last').after(a);   
    a='';
    }

  });
  
  

});

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed ! `'+file.name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")+'`

```
var a = '<div class="as"><input placeholder="caption" type="text" value="'+file.name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")+'" name="caption[]" id="'+element.id+'_caption'+'"></input><input name="alttext1[]" placeholder="Alt text" type="text" id="'+element.id+'_alttext1'+'"></input></div>';
```

I forget the add my website : [PBR Textures](https://www.sharetextures.com/)